# Matlab plot polygon from sensordata

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an array of different length measurements to the walls of an arbitrarily shaped box from a point. They are taken during a 360 degree rotation and I also have a degree measurement.

```
Distance(1:k);   % distance to wall of arbitrarily shaped box during a rotation
Degree(1:k);   % degrees rotated from first measurement
Time(1:k); % time passed since first  measurement
```

How can I used `distance` and `Time/Distance` to plot a shape that would look  like the shape of the box? I tried  the convhull function, wondering if there are better options.

Comment: Is your point you calculate your distances from fixed (modulo the rotations)?

Comment: From a fixed point. Anywhere inside a box. F.ex a rectangle, an octagon etc. For every time the sensor turns clockwise 1 degree it also gets a length measurement to the side of the box.

Comment: Okay. Could you provide some sample input and the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

```
Rads=Degrees*(2*pi/360);
X=Distance.*cos(Rads);
Y=Distance.*sin(Rads);
plot(X,Y);
```